# FatalErrorException in Laravel using c9.io - a view I didn't create and can't find

Tags: php, laravel

I am following along with a Udemy tutorial: https://www.udemy.com/modern-web-development-with-laravel on "Routing: POST Requests".

This is the error message I'm getting:

FatalErrorException in 5fdc953597d1005dc73a20900434960e537f9180.php line 16:
syntax error, unexpected ':'

I did not create a view by that name nor do I see it in the file directory in my c9.io IDE.

My routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/greet/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return view('actions.greet', ['name' => $name]);
})->name('greet');

Route::get('/hug', function () {
    return view('actions.hug');
})->name('hug');

Route::get('/kiss', function () {
    return view('actions.kiss');
})->name('kiss');

Route::post('/benice', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    if(isset($request['action']) && isset($request['name'])){
        if(strlen($request['name'])>0){
            return view('nice', ['action'=> $request['action'], 'name'=>$request['name']]);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

})->name('benice');
```

-

Sorry again that I am very much a beginner, could not find this problem anywhere else on Google/Stacksocial, need help.

Comment: Please add the code of your view file of the route that you are getting this error on (i am guessing `nice.blade.php`).

Comment: this is the compiled view file. Laravel automatically, will create a view file that has all the files included.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is happening when you make a mistake with your blade.
This error is in your blade template. This is Laravel generated view placed inside `/storage/framework/views`

To check this, go to this folder and open `5fdc953597d1005dc73a20900434960e537f9180.php` view.

Check what is in line 16, you may used `:` instead of `;` in your original blade.

You have to correct your original blade file, not this `5fdc953597d1005dc73a20900434960e537f9180.php` laravel generated view.